# subqueries foxpro

Tags: sql, subquery, visual-foxpro

```
SELECT category, SUM(price*amount);
 FROM dan2.dbf WHERE;
  between(date_p, {^2014-01-01}, {^2014-12-31});
    GROUP BY category
```

[image]

This query finds the sum of categories and some conditions on date. I need to find the maximum of the sum (by the subkuery).

Comment: In more normal SQL, you could add something like `ORDER BY 2 DESC LIMIT 1` or `ORDER BY 2 DESC FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY`.

Comment: I need to do it by MAX and subquery

Comment: But then you will have one MAX only, so do you want to repeat it for every category? Or are you talking about a completely different query that only returns the MAX?

Comment: My query has already sums are grouped by categories. I need an external query that returns max=34840.00

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Details would depend on the VFP version you are using - in the most recent VFP 9, you could do something like

```
* create test data
CREATE CURSOR test (id Int, category Int, price Num(15,2), amount Int, dateP D)
INSERT INTO test VALUES (1, 2, 24.25, 15, {^2014-10-5})
INSERT INTO test VALUES (2, 2, 700.0, 15, {^2014-7-25})
INSERT INTO test VALUES (3, 2, 110.10, 210, {^2015-11-15})
INSERT INTO test VALUES (4, 3, 110.10, 11, {^2014-11-15})

* your original 
SELECT category, SUM(price*amount) ;
    FROM test ;
    WHERE datep Between {^2014-01-01} And {^2014-12-31} ;
    GROUP BY category

* your desired result w/o sub-query
SELECT SUM(price*amount) ;
    FROM test ;
    WHERE datep Between {^2014-01-01} And {^2014-12-31} 

* the desired sub-query you described
SELECT SUM(Total) ;
    FROM ( ;
        SELECT category, SUM(price*amount) As Total ;
            FROM test ;
            WHERE datep Between {^2014-01-01} And {^2014-12-31} ;
            GROUP BY category ;
            ) As subQuery
```

Edited:

```
* as per your comment
SELECT TOP 1 category, Max(Total) ;
    FROM ( ;
        SELECT category, SUM(price*amount) As Total ;
            FROM test ;
            WHERE datep Between {^2014-01-01} And {^2014-12-31} ;
            GROUP BY category ;
            ) As subQuery ;
    GROUP BY 1 ;
    ORDER BY 2 Desc
```

Comment: No. I need an external query to get the MAX of these lines (not SUM), i.e. 38840 in  my example and  10863.75 in your

Comment: Thank you, it's right. This is the only possible solution? Is it possible to do so without "ORDER BY"?

Comment: The last one was assuming you somehow do want to `Select .. From (yourSubQuery)` explicitly, say because you are concatenating SQL statements in some generic way. A simplified solution could select from the table directly, similar to the "your desired result w/o sub-query" version in the reply. The "Order By" in the most recent one was for the "Top 1" part assuming you want only the Maxi()mum

Answer (score 1):

> I need to find the maximum of the sum

You could easily get the maximum of the sum values by a single query and using an ORDER DESC on the query and then getting the TOP value.

```
SELECT category,  
SUM(price*amount) AS Sum_Val;  
FROM dan2.dbf WHERE;  
between(date_p, {^2014-01-01}, {^2014-12-31});  
GROUP BY category  
ORDER BY 2 DESC  
INTO CURSOR TmpResults  

SELECT TmpResults  
GO TOP  
MaxSum = TmpResults.Sum_Val
```

Good Luck